# How do I do a partial field match using Haystack?

Tags: django, search, search-engine, django-haystack

I needed a simple search tool for my django-powered web site, so I went with Haystack and Solr. I have set everything up correctly and can find the correct search results when I type in the **exact** phrase, but I can't get any results when typing in a partial phrase.

For example: "John" returns "John Doe" but "Joh" doesn't return anything.

Model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Search Index:

```
class PersonIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    first_name = CharField(model_attr = 'first_name')
    last_name = CharField(model_attr = 'last_name')

site.register(Person, PersonIndex)
```

I'm guessing there's some setting I'm missing that enables partial field matching. I've seen people talking about `EdgeNGramFilterFactory()` in some forums, and I've Googled it, but I'm not quite sure of its implementation. Plus, I was hoping there was a haystack-specific way of doing it in case I ever switch out the search backend.

Answer (score 16):

You can achieve that behavior by making your index's text field an EdgeNgramField:

```
class PersonIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    first_name = CharField(model_attr = 'first_name')
    last_name = CharField(model_attr = 'last_name')
```

Comment: I'm using elasticsearch & haystack and this do the trick of partial match perfectly, saving myself of some hours of elasticsearch configuration

Comment: @Liarez how did you get this to work? I'm using haystack/elastic search and I wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `EdgeNgramField` hint that others mentioned in this page (and of course `NgramField`, if you work with Asian languages), I think it is worth to mention that in Django_haystack you can run raw queries on Solr via following command:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.inputs import Raw
SearchQuerySet().filter(text=Raw(query))
```

where `text` is the field you want to search, and the `query` can be anything based on Query Parser Syntax (version [3.6](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html), or [4.6](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description)) of Lucene.

In this way you can easily set the query to `ABC*` or `ABC~` or anything else which fits to the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while searching for non english words, for instance:

```
ABC
ABCD
```

If I want to search for keywords `ABC`, I will expect the above two results.  I was able to achieve the following by converting the keyword to lowercase and using `startswith`:

```
keywords = 'ABC'
results.filter(code__startswith=keywords.lower())
```

Comment: Of course it won't, the case I illustrated was to search for prefixes only.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the only way to get the results I wanted was to modify the solr configuration file to include ngram filtering as the default tokenizer is based on white space. So use [NGramTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/analysis/NGramTokenizerFactory.html) instead.  I'd love to know if there was a haystack way of doing the same thing.

I'm not at my machine right now but this should do the trick.

```
<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@riz I can't comment yet or I would and I know it's an old comment but in case anyone else runs past this:  Make sure to manage.py update_index

> Blockquote @Liarez how did you get this to work? I'm using haystack/elastic search and I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Update didn't work for me but rebuild_index did. Watch out if your index is big!