# Returning partial results with elasticsearch (django-haystack)

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

How can I make django-haystack return results for `joey` as well when searching for `joe` for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do a partial field match using Haystack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391631/how-do-i-do-a-partial-field-match-using-haystack)

Comment: @mevius there's no solution on that question and the highest rated doesn't work.