# can't get partial word search to work with haystack/elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm trying to get partial word match working and I've already looked at [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391631/how-do-i-do-a-partial-field-match-using-haystack) but for some reason my setup doesn't work. I'm using haystack with elasticsearch. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class VendorIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name', null=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Vendor

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

EDIT: I've made this work by making use of autocomplete. However, I feel like this is a hack. But here is my code:

```
class VendorIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name', null=True)
    company_name_auto = indexes.NgramField(model_attr='company_name')
    def get_model(self):
        return Vendor

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

then in the View:

```
class SearchVendorView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomerVendorSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        results = SearchQuerySet().models(Vendor).autocomplete(company_name_auto=self.request.GET.get('q', ''))
        vendors = []

        for vendor in [result.object for result in results]:
            vendor.is_liked = Vendor.objects.from_request(self.request).get(pk=vendor.id).user_vote  
            vendors.append(vendor)      

        return vendors
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case: `django-haystack==2.5.1` + `elasticsearch==5.0.1` + `java elastic search daemon v2.3.1` this is enough to get partial search:

```py
from haystack import indexes
from authors.models import Author


class AuthorIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name')
    first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Author

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

And then `python manage.py rebuild_index` and you can search by:

```py
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
SearchQuerySet().filter(content="alex")
```

to find `Alexander`.

Comment: Do you know if this will work on `elasticsearch 1.x`?

Comment: Nathan, nope, i never user elasticsearch v.1.